# Creating SASS override for white labelled application

Tags: css, sass

I'm running a white label application where many brands are using a set of SASS variables. But over the time, it happens that additional variables needs to be added for a given breakpoint in order to allow more flexibility. Thus, in order to keep backward compatibility, I assign the current value to the newly created variable (`$test--large`). For the brand, to be able to customize style for large breakpoint.

The issue is that it doesn't work the way i'd expect it to work. If at brand level, I change `$test`, i'd like `$test--large` to also have the new value assignment.

Hope it makes sense, if not what would you suggest. Knowing that we have many brands and it would be painful to redefine all the new variables.

```scss
$test: blue !default;
$test--large: $test !default;  // new variable

$test: green; // Override from brand

.text {
  color: $test;

  // Newly added piece

  @include breakpoint(large) {
      color: $test--large; //result will be blue but i'd expect it to be green
  }

}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you assign `$test` to `$test--large`, the variable is being passed by value, not reference. Hence when you reassign `$test` to green, you need to also reassign `$test--large`, e.g. like this:

```
$test--large: $test
```

or

```
$test--large: green
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, that's what I wanted to avoid. If i'm adding new variable, I don't want all my brand project to reassigned to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to avoid this solution because it will require me to change it in all my project.
The variables override need to happen before and not after the `!default` values

I'm still wondering if it isn't possible without interchanging the variable import order

```scss
$test: green; // Override from brand

$test: blue !default;
$test--large: $test !default;  // new variable

.text {
  color: $test;

  // Newly added piece

  @include breakpoint(large) {
      color: $test--large; //result will be green as expected
  }

}
```